# How to attach database after uploading website to server using core ftp?

Tags: database, web, server

I uploaded complete website to server using Core FTP but i want to connect database and dashboard for website.

How to connect the database to website?

Please help me out....

I tried to connect using

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'applicants');
```

OR

```
$con = mysqli_connect('IP Address or web URL', 'root', '', 'applicants');
```

Comment: Are you using PHP? and which DB you are trying to connect

Comment: Yes, I have created DB using phpmyadmin in xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option looks correct as 1st option doesn't have password in call.
DO as  below example:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Here **localhost** is MySql server location
**my_user**  is userId of MySql
**my_password** is Password of MySql
**my_db** is database name of MySql